# How to have executable code in a markdown cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to have a markdown cell that calls a variable in previous code ran, for example:

Code cell:
`a = 0.00234...`

Markdown cell:
`so, a is (insert code to display exact number)`

I have used the nbextension "Python Markdown" which utilizes double curly brackets `{{a}}`

However, that extension does not work, and yes my notebook is trusted. Please help if you can. Thank you for your time.